# How to change Buttons in Android DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker

When I want to choose a day or a time in my Android Calendar App, a DatePicker opens. In this Datepicker, there are two buttons. The **left one is labeled "Cancel"**, the **right one is labeled "Set"**.
In my Android application, I also have a DatePicker. In this DatePicker, the **left Button is labeled "Set"** and the **right button is labeled "Cancel"**.

**Why does these two Apps behave in a different way?**

**Does anyone knows, why the Buttons in these DatePickers are in a different order?**

My Activity which calls the DatePickerFragment:

```
public void chooseDate(View v) {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.setCalendar(termin);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

My DatePickerFragment class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Calendar getCalendar() {
        return calendar;
    }

    public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        ((DatePickerMenu) getActivity()).setDate(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks in the Calendar App:
[image]

This is how it looks in My App:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of this datepicker?

Comment: Uploaded two screenshots :-)

Comment: Take a look at an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418118/1808829

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

**Remember**: You can set a title using `builder.setTitle()`, in the screen i keep it empty because i don't know what you want to do with the title.

[image]

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(this);
picker.setCalendarViewShown(false);

builder.setView(picker);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.setPositiveButton("Set", null);
builder.show();
```

If you want to extend `DialogFragment` you can use the same code, and override `onCreateDialog`.

---

[image]

I used an AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCustomTitle(new DatePicker(this));
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.setPositiveButton("Set", null);
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Datepicker that appears in the application varies depending on the devices used. For the latest versions and advanced mobile phones the datepicker appearance varies compared to lower versions of android phones.